# Can SPSiteDataQuery search both List and Libraries?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have the following code:

```
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"UniqueId\" />";
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";
query.Query = "<Where<Eq><FieldRef Name='MyCustomField' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";
query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType=\"1\" />";
DataTable results = site.RootWeb.GetSiteData(query);
```

This searches all the Document Libraries in the site collection, but I want to search all the Lists as well. Is there a way to set the [Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx) property to search both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is.

SPSiteDataQuery targets 1 specific kind of content (i.e. list type) at a time.

When you need results from different kinds of content that, for instance, share a common custom field, create a managed property in Search (in the Shared Service Provider) and then use the [FullTextSqlQuery](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/03/06/how-to-use-the-moss-enterprise-search-fulltextsqlquery-class.aspx) class to query all content (which works cross site collection also, seeing as it is using the MOSS Search index).